# Run Shortcode of post's custom field in functions.php / Plugin

Tags: plugin-development, custom-field, shortcode, the-content, post-meta

After 3 or 4 hours of searching the web for a solution, I abandoned it and hopefully you can help me?

1. I added a **sub-headline** as a **custom field** (*subheadlineclass*). That works pretty. I can save, edit and open it in WordPress' post-editor.
2. There is a **shortcode** in this custom field to generate this sub-title dynamically. (I use [PHP Code for posts](https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/php-code-for-posts/) to do so.)

3.1. Also, it's no problem to call this custom field (as a executed shortcode) in my **template** with:

```
if (!empty(get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "subheadlineclass", true))) {
$subheadline = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "subheadlineclass", true);
$subheadline = do_shortcode(subheadline);
}
```

3.2. This lines are placed in the index.php (inside the loop). After this, I can use the variable *$subheadline* to place the sub-headline, wherever I want (for example below the title).

3.3. Of course you need to add this to the functions.php:

```
add_filter( "the_content", 'do_shortcode');
```

4. Anyway, now to the problem: I outsourced many snippets from the **functions.php** to a "plugin" (actually it doesn't matter, if it's the functions.php or placed in a plugin to solve this issue). At this place I **cannot use this snippet** any longer. The string is empty.

BUT this *var_dump* tells me, the shortcode isn't just executed:

```
$shortcode = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'subheadlineclass',true);
var_dump($shortcode);
```

Output:

```
string(40) "[php snippet=1 param="subheadline=1"]"
```

Soooo I cann call the variable of the custom field, but **do_shortcode** (like in 3.1.) doesn't work. But why? And how can this problem be solved? Thanks!

Comment: Can you expand on "doesn't work" from the last paragraph? Have you tried echoing `$shortcode`, e.g. `$shortcode = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(),'subheadlineclass',true); echo $shortcode;`

Comment: Sorry, for didn't myself clear. The snippet in 3.1. works not like in 4., when I put it to the functions.php. Your example: `echo $shortcode;` leads to an empty string (I mentioned that at "Output"). Nevertheless, at THIS position, there is just the shortcode as plaintext, not the executed shortcode, which you can do via `do_shortcode`.